# Converting csv to to xlsx but TextQualifier and EOL don't work

Tags: c#, excel, csv, epplus

I have gotten a csv file that consists of 7 columns and around 100 rows. A row would look likes this:

```
A-1,1,ABC,01/01/2024,"a,sentence","a, paragraph in one cell
with some, line breaks
with some, line breaks", another sentence
```

I tried converting the csv using EPPLUS

```
FileInfo csvFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1 , csvData.Count, colCount].LoadFromText(csvFile, format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Custom, true);
}
```

I don't know if the paragraph cells that contain line breaks are messing with EPPLUS but for some reason it is having difficulty detecting the EOL. All lines are loaded into row 1. Not only that, the paragraph cell would be split into 4 cells due to it containing the delimiter

I have tried adding `format.TextQualifier = '\"';` but I would get the this error `Text delimiter is not closed in line:` and the line in question is the entire csv file bc it is loading the whole csv file as 1 single line...Adding `format.EOL = "\r\n";` or `format.EOL = "\r";` doesn't do anything, all data will still be loaded into row 1 with the same incorrect splitting. Setting `firstRowIsHeader` as true doesn't do anything either as again it can't detect when a new row starts.

I can't alter the original csv file to change its delimiter or fix its line breaks. How can I fix the EOL and use TextQualifier? Am I missing something? Please!

Comment: Have you tried CSVHelper? Not sure if any of the two are capable of that, but you'd need to have them separately handle linebreaks _inside_ TextQualifiers and _outside_.

Comment: Of course, with that type of format, you could **Open** the file directly in Excel and save it as an `xlsx` file. Or if there were issues with dates or numbers, you could **Import** it into Excel using either `Power Query` or the `legacy wizard`.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your reply. I didn't try out CsvHelper but your comment gave me the idea to try out different EOL and I can now break the lines properly and use a TextQualifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format.EOL = "\r\n"` and `format.EOL = "\r";` didn't work but `format.EOL = "\n";` does work. After some trials and errors I set this as the EOL and can finally set the TextQualifier without running into that "Text delimiter is not closed in line" error, and everything is splitting correctly now.